# Unable to clip/crop images

Tags: playn

The following code is intend to draw numbers on screen using a image strip and some nails on canvas, but it is not displaying.

1) When i comment/remove "setSourceRect", it displays the complete image.
2) the initnails function is not displaying anything

```
package com.myGame.mavenproject3.core; 
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.CircleShape; 
import playn.core.*; 
import static playn.core.PlayN.assetManager; 
import static playn.core.PlayN.graphics; 

public class mavenproject3 implements Game { 
 Canvas canvas; 
    private float radius; 
    Image pointsFontImage; 
 GroupLayer pointsLayer; 
@Override 
  public void init() { 
// create and add background image layer 
int width = 640; 
int height = 480; 
CanvasImage bgImage = graphics().createImage(width, height); 
canvas = bgImage.canvas(); 
canvas.setFillColor(0xff87ceeb); 
canvas.fillRect(0, 0, width, height); 
ImageLayer bg = graphics().createImageLayer(bgImage); 
graphics().rootLayer().add(bg); 
pointsLayer = graphics().createGroupLayer(); 
  pointsLayer.setScale(3.0f, 3.0f); 
  pointsFontImage = assetManager().getImage("images/font.png"); 
  graphics().rootLayer().add(pointsLayer); 
  } 
  @Override 
  public void paint(float alpha) { 
// the background automatically paints itself, so no need to do 
anything here! 
  } 
int points = 50; 
  @Override 
  public void update(float delta) { 
  initNails(); 
  float x = 0f; 
  pointsLayer.clear(); 
  for (char c : Integer.toString(points).toCharArray()) { 
    ImageLayer digit = graphics().createImageLayer(pointsFontImage); 
    digit.setSourceRect(((c - '0' + 9) % 10) * 16, 0, 16, 16); 
    pointsLayer.add(digit); 
    digit.setTranslation(x, 0f); 
    x += 16f; 
  } 
  } 
  @Override 
  public int updateRate() { 
    return 25; 
  } 
  public void initNails() { 
  for (int x = 100; x < 300 - 100; x += 50) { 
    for (int y = 150; y < 450; y+= 100) { 
        canvas.setFillColor(0xffaaaaaa); 
        canvas.fillCircle(x, y, radius); 
    CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape(); 
    circleShape.m_radius = 5f*2; 
    circleShape.m_p.set(x*2, 
                        y*2); 
    } 
  } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the source rect, you need to set the target dimensions for the image layer, otherwise they will be the same as the size of the original image. The original image is 160x16, but you want to render a single character, so you should have 16x16:

```
ImageLayer digit = graphics().createImageLayer(pointsFontImage); 
digit.setSourceRect(((c - '0' + 9) % 10) * 16, 0, 16, 16); 
digit.setWidth(16);
digit.setHeight(16);
pointsLayer.add(digit); 
digit.setTranslation(x, 0f);
```

I also can't resist pointing out that this is **hugely** inefficient in multiple ways.

The `update()` method runs 60 times per second (in an ideal world). You are needlessly creating and destroying image layers every frame. You should create an image layer once for each potential digit and then just update its source rect every frame. You are also obtaining the digits of your `points` value in an extravagantly expensive manner as well.

The following code is less likely to make a game developer cry themselves to sleep at night:

```
int points = 50;

final float DIGIT_WIDTH = 16;
final float DIGIT_HEIGHT = 16;
final int MAX_DIGITS = 5;

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
  initNails();

  // peel off the right-most digit of points and update its layer;
  // creating the layer on demand if we don't have one yet
  int ll = 0;
  for (int p = points; p > 0 || ll == 0; p /= 10, ll++) {
    ImageLayer digit;
    if (pointsLayer.size() <= ll) {
      digit = graphics().createImageLayer(pointsFontImage);
      digit.setWidth(DIGIT_WIDTH);
      digit.setHeight(DIGIT_HEIGHT);
      digit.setTranslation((MAX_DIGITS-ll-1) * DIGIT_WIDTH, 0);
      pointsLayer.add(digit);
    } else {
      digit = (ImageLayer)pointsLayer.get(ll);
      digit.setVisible(true);
    }
    int d = p%10, ix = ((d + 9) % 10);
    digit.setSourceRect(ix * DIGIT_WIDTH, 0, DIGIT_WIDTH, DIGIT_HEIGHT);
  }
  // hide layers for leading zeros
  while (ll < pointsLayer.size()) {
    pointsLayer.get(ll++).setVisible(false);
  }
}
```